# Is there a Lua function for the `G` motion in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

## Goal

I want to jump to line 55. I can do this with a normal motion in Vim. I can do this programmatically from Lua using `vim.cmd`. But is there a dedicated Lua function for this?

### Vim normal motion

`55`[`G`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/motion.html#G)

### Vim normal motion from Lua

```lua
local line = 55
vim.cmd('normal ' .. line .. 'G')
```

### Dedicated Lua function

```lua
local line = 55
-- <your answer here>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua way of doing this is using `vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor` call.

```lua
local line = 55
vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor(0, {line, 0})
```

(or)

You can use `:55` in `command` mode to switch to 55th line.

So in lua..

```lua
local line = 55
vim.cmd(":"..line)
```